# Prestashop PayPal module won't save settings

Tags: paypal, prestashop-1.6

After I install the module and complete my API credentials I click the "save" button and I always get the following error:

> Error !
>
> You need to complete the PayPal identification Information in step 3
>   otherwise you won't be able to accept payment.

I already uninstalled and reinstalled the module.

PrestaShop version: 1.6.1.4

PayPal version: 3.10.6

Comment: Did you contact the developper of the module ?

Comment: Yes, there is an open ticket since Friday but no response.

Answer (score 0):

Because of You install module that is unknown if it support PayPal's latest changes or not.

Seems like when You click save button it send CURL request to PayPal and tires to get necessary data. But response is not same as supposed to be.

If You're PHP dev: **You've to debug that module**, 
otherwise: **find someone to fix it**.